# Error storing int after string in dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++, malloc

I'm trying out a program in which I create 24 bytes of memory space using `malloc`. The idea is to store a name (string) in the first 10 bytes and the age (int) in the next 2 bytes in a `12 byte` spectrum. I wish to do this for two sets of data, hence I allocate **2 x 12 = 24 bytes**. I want to use the space as a **heterogeneous 2D array**.

The picture below illustrates how I want to organize the memory space.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
void* ptr = malloc(24);
string* st;
string t_string;
int i=0, c=1, t_int;
int* it;

while(i < 24){
    cout << "Enter name and age (" << (c++) << "): ";
    cin >> t_string >> t_int;
    st = (string*)(ptr) + i;
    *st = t_string;
    it = (int*)(ptr) + i + 10;
    *it = t_int;

    i+=12;
}

cout << endl;

i=0;
while(i < 24){
    st =  (string*)(ptr) + i;
    it = (int*)(ptr) + i + 10;
    cout << *st << " is " << *it << " years old.\n";

    i+= 12;
}
```

The problem is when I enter two names and ages, the first age is always shown wrong. Here's an output:

```
Enter name and age (1): Progyammer 19
Enter name and age (2): Coderguy00 19

Progyammer is 1629513069 years old.
Coderguy00 is 19 years old.
```

EVERY TIME, IT HAPPENS ONLY WITH THE FIRST PERSON'S AGE.

### Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think you're confusing `std::string` with `char[]`...

Comment: This program is wrong so many ways, it's hard to tell where to start.

Comment: @John3136 I think it returns a pointer to the ith memory location after `ptr` to `st`. I basically do that to store the next string in the 13th memory location, after having stored the first name and age in the first 12 locations.

Comment: @RSahu I'm a complete C/C++ n00b. I'm just experimenting.

Comment: @John3136 I believe that is possible, but I'm too amateur to understand where I'm doing it exactly.

Comment: When you want to maintain a relationship between various unrelated types of information, you use a `struct` (or since you tagged the question as C++, you can also use a `class`), but then you shouldn't be using `malloc` as C++ provides `new`.

Comment: You can only assign to a valid string, and you need to ensure that it's properly aligned. You also need to study how pointer arithmetic works.

Comment: Why do I thought that pointer arithmetic is only for array navigation in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you should really be using a `struct` in C or `class` in C++, but if you are stack-space constrained on some micro-controller such that the extra 4-bytes of padding per-12-byte block make a difference, there is no reason you cannot do exactly what you want to do -- but I would advise using C instead of C++ for that type of hackery. Also if you are just doing this for a learning project, for handling a generic block of data, to learn about the *strict aliasing rule* [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6), and to learn about addressing within a block -- that's fine too.

First off you will want to create your 24-byte block of allocate memory as type `char` (see *§6.5 Expressions* above). Once you have allocated/validated storage for a block of memory, then is it up to you to create the logic to store and access the information you wish within the block. (you don't have an array of 12-byte blocks, you just have a 24-byte block, so array indexing will do you no good, it is pointer arithmetic or nothing.

There really is nothing difficult about the pointer arithmetic needed. You know you will need to treat each 12-byte block as a storage area. So looping over your block of memory you can use your (`pointer + i * BLKSZ12`) to locate the beginning of each 12-byte block. From there, you know your `short` will be stored another `STRSZ` (i.e. `10`) bytes from the beginning. So as you loop, you can store or access each corresponding `short` with `pointer + i * BLKSZ12 + STRSZ`. It is then just a simple matter of storing or retrieving the `age` from that offset.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRSZ 10
#define BLKSZ 12
#define BUFSZ 512

int main (void) {

    char *block,            /* pointer to generic block of memory */
        buf[BUFSZ] = "";    /* buffer for fgets use */
    size_t i = 0,           /* general loop var / counter */
        nblks = 2;          /* number of BLKSZ blocks to allocate */

    /* allocate block of nblks * BLKSZ bytes / validate */
    if (!(block = malloc (nblks * BLKSZ))) {
        perror ("malloc-block");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (i < nblks) {     /* for each of the blocks */
        size_t len;         /* var for holding string length */
        printf ("\nenter name (9 char max): "); /* prompt/validate */
        if (!fgets (buf, BUFSZ, stdin)) {   /* read/validate input */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: user canceled input.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        len = strlen (buf);                 /* get length */
        if (len && buf[len - 1] == '\n')    /* check trailing '\n' */
            buf[--len] = 0;                 /* overwrite w/nul-character */
        else if (len == BUFSZ - 1) {        /* check all input fit in buf */
            fprintf (stderr, "error input too long or buf.\n");
            continue;           /* go get next name */
        }
        if (len > STRSZ - 1) {  /* validate name fits */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: name exceeds %d chars.\n", STRSZ - 1);
            continue;
        }
        strcpy (block + i * BLKSZ, buf);
        printf ("enter age              : "); /* prompt/validate */
        if (!fgets (buf, BUFSZ, stdin)) {   /* read/validate input */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: user canceled input.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }   /* convert age to short from buf */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%hd", (short*)(block + i * BLKSZ + STRSZ)) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion failed, block %zu.\n", i);
            continue;
        }
        i++;    /* we got a valid block, increment block count */
    }

    printf ("\nNames       Age\n");
    for (i = 0; i < nblks; i++) /* output info stored in each block */
        printf ("%-10s  %2hd yrs.\n", block + i * BLKSZ, 
                *(short*)(block + i * BLKSZ + STRSZ));

    free (block);   /* free block */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/alloc_blk24

enter name (9 char max): Mary
enter age              : 25

enter name (9 char max): Joeseph
enter age              : 90

Names       Age
Mary        25 yrs.
Joeseph     90 yrs.
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

Any time you dynamically allocate memory in C, it is up to you to verify you have used that memory properly, there are no memory errors and that all memory you have allocated has been freed. On Linux the `valgrind` tool is the tool of choice. All OS's have similar tools. They are simple to use, you just run your program through them.

For example, using `valgrind` you can confirm that you allocated only a single 24-byte block of memory, that there were no memory errors, and that all memory you allocated had been properly freed before the program executed, e.g.

```
valgrind ./bin/alloc_blk24
==26366== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26366== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26366== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26366== Command: ./bin/alloc_blk24
==26366==

enter name (9 char max): Mary
enter age              : 25

enter name (9 char max): Joeseph
enter age              : 89

Names       Age
Mary        25 yrs.
Joeseph     89 yrs.
==26366==
==26366== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26366==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26366==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==26366==
==26366== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==26366==
==26366== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26366== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As all have advised, me included, this is not the way you should approach using a block of memory to hold two unrelated data type (absent being on memory-critical hardware, or using it for a learning exercise). The upside is C provides all the tools needed to do this, just for the reasons discussed. C will let you do just about anything that can be done on a computer with lightning speed -- whether or not you should -- is just another aspect of the question.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

You're going about this the wrong way. You would be much better off creating an array of structs that contain a nine-character (plus the null character) char pointer, with a short (not an int, which is 4 bytes) for the age.

```
struct Person {
    const char name[10];
    short age;
};
```

You could then create your two Person array like this:

```
struct Person arr[2] /* the 2 is optional */ = { 
    {"Haskell", 12}, {"Ada", 21} 
};
```

Comment: If you really want a two byte int, better to `#include <cstdint>` and use `int16_t`

Comment: While your advice is good, your terminology is wrong. Your struct contains a 10-char *array*, not a "nine-character (plus the null character) char pointer". Interestingly if you actually had designed the struct with a char pointer (`char *` or `const char *`), the code in the second group would still work as written, but the content of the strings themselves would not be stored in the array, only pointers to the actual strings that would be somewhere else in memory.